# How to iterate a list of list and updating the elements in the list using only list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists of bookshop orders:

```
orders = [ [1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
           [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733", 11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)] ]
```

The number 1,2,3,4 is the order number, and the elements in the tuples are 'book number', 'quantity', and 'price'. I want to combine the 'quantity' and 'price' into 1 element which is the 'total price' if the total price is less than 100 'total price + 10".

```
m1_list = []
for row in orders:
    lst = [row[0]]
    for column in row[1:len(row)]:
        order_num, quantity, price = column
        product = float(quantity) * float(price)
        if product < 100:
            total_price = product + 10
        else:
            total_price = product
        tpl = (order_num, total_price)
        lst.append(tpl)
    m1_list.append(lst)
print(m1_list)
```

and this is the output:

```
[[1, ('5464', 49.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)], 
 [2, ('5464', 99.91), ('9744', 404.55)], 
 [3, ('5464', 99.91), ('88112', 274.89)], 
 [4, ('8732', 93.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]]
```

How do I do the same thing as above using only list comprehension, as I'm not allowed to use iteration/loop?

Comment: has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works. Try it.

```
new_lst2 = [[y if type(y) != tuple else (y[0], y[1]*y[2]+10) if y[1]*y[2] < 100 else (y[0], y[1]*y[2]) for y in x] for x in orders]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math as m

orders =  [[line[0]] + [(tuples[0], (m.prod(tuples[1:]) if m.prod(tuples[1:]) > 100 else m.prod(tuples[1:]) + 10)) for tuples in line[1:]] for line in orders]


print(orders)

>>> orders =  [[1, ('5464', 49.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)], [2, ('5464', 99.91), ('9744', 404.55)], [3, ('5464', 99.91), ('88112', 274.89)], [4, ('8732', 93.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]]]
```

You can use `pprint` to print it nicer

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(orders)

>>> [[1, ('5464', 49.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)],
     [2, ('5464', 99.91), ('9744', 404.55)],
     [3, ('5464', 99.91), ('88112', 274.89)],
     [4, ('8732', 93.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Best I can think of is this way:

```py
orders = [ [1, ("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [2, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           [3, ("5464", 9, 9.99), ("88112", 11, 24.99)],
           [4, ("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733", 11,18.99), ("88112", 5, 39.95)] ]

def total(z):
    if type(z) == tuple:
        if z[1]*z[2] < 100:
            return (z[0], z[1]*z[2]+10)
        return (z[0], z[1]*z[2])
    return z

new_lst = [ list(map(total, x)) for x in orders]

print(new_lst)
```

Comment: the op said only to use list comprehension

Comment: sorry im also new to python, just trying my best to help.